# check if user is logged in and then check if user was logged in with a radio button checked

Tags: php

this is my first post here so please be gentle on the comments.

I have a website Ii am playing with. it has a basic login page / registration page. if a user is not logged in he has access to all pages but is not able to see prices. when user is logged in prices become available. my question is how do i make it so when the user is on the login page he has an option to select one of two radio buttons and with that selected user will be logged in and content specific to either of the radio button will be shown.. i.e: login and have high prices clicked (once logged in i can see prices that are high) logout and click on login with low prices checked then i see only low prices.

here is my code for login.php

```
<?php
require('db.php');
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username'])){

    $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); //escapes special characters in a string
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

//Checking is user existing in the database or not
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
        }else{
            echo "<div class='form'><h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login_page.php'>Login</a></div>";
            }
}else{?>

<!-- header ends here -->
<!-- ****************************************** -->
<!-- enquiry / newsletter / login / register goes here -->
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- Main page content goes here -->
<div class="content_landing">
<p><div class="form">
<h2>Log In to view Prices and Specials</h2>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="birthday" checked> Birthday Prices<br>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="corporate"> Corporate Prices<br>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required /><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required /><br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<p>Not registered yet? <a href='registration.php'>Register Here</a></p>
</div></p>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

once the user is logged in he sees this content (on the products.php: (should he go to it)

```
<p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ?>
<p>Pricing below:</p>
<p><a class="link" href="logout.php" style="text-decoration:none">Logout</a></p>
<?php }else{ ?>
  <a class="link" href="login_page.php" style="text-decoration:none">login</a> or <a class="link" href="registration_page.php" style="text-decoration:none">Register</a>
<?php } ?>
```

I am still a super noob at webdesigning so please forgive my indenting and methods and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just assign a new session variable that you check when displaying pricing:

```
<?php
require('db.php');
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['view_type'] = (!empty($_POST['corporate']))? 'c' : 'b';
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "<div class='form'><h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login_page.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }
} else { ?>...etc.
```

To use the variable, it would be wise to make a function or two so you are not repeating yourself over and over with a bunch of `if/else`:

```
# Checks if user is corporate
function isCorporate()
    {
        return (isset($_SESSION['view_type']) && $_SESSION['view_type'] == 'c');
    }
# Checks if user is birthday
function isBirthday()
    {
        return (isset($_SESSION['view_type']) && $_SESSION['view_type'] == 'b');
    }
# Checks if user is logged in at all
function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return (!empty($_SESSION['username']));
    }
```

So you would do something like:

```
# Logged In?
if(isLoggedIn()) {
    # What kind of login?
    echo (isCorporate())? 'Higher value' : 'Lower value';
}
else
    # Not logged in...
    echo 'Log in to see price!';
```

Check against `$_SESSION['view_type']` when deciding the price view.

To just have the view type only, you can use either same form with a checkbox that if checked, will allow your logic to ignore the username and password fields you can have a separate form with those, you could have a couple of style `<a>` links that look like radio button, etc. There are many ways you can make the session create the view without logging in the user fully.

Couple side notes, you should not escape the user submissions, you should be binding parameters instead. By binding parameters, it means you don't put your variables right into the sql statement like you have now. Secondly, you should be using `password_hash()` / `password_verify()` for storing and retrieval of password hash. `md5()` is not sufficient for security. Lastly add `exit` after you redirect using `header()`, it will stop any further execution of the script, even if there is nothing after, it's good habit to do so.

One note about the functions, you need only store them in an includable file and just use `require_once('myfunctions.php');` to include them at the top of the page.

---

EDIT:

---

So based on your code snippet from the comment:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ?>
    <p>Pricing below:</p>
    <?php if(isCorporate()) { ?>
    <h1>$100</h1>
    <?php } elseif(isBirthday()) { ?>
    <h3>$50</h3>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <p><em>NOT SET YET</em></p>
    <?php } ?>
    <p><a class="link" href="logout.php" style="text-decoration:none">Logout</a></p>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a class="link" href="login_page.php" style="text-decoration:none">login</a> or <a class="link" href="registration_page.php" style="text-decoration:none">Register</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @verjas i basically want a user to login either to view corporate or birthday party prices or if they are not logged in just to view the pages content. once they logged in the products page will show either corporate price or birthday price. i am not using a database for the storing of the prices... they are in the if isset of the products page under each product description.

Comment: Yeah, that is fine, then what I am showing you will work.

Comment: If you want them to just be able to click a button, you can just create  separate form where they can submit just those two options and you just set the view type.

Comment: is there a way for us to chat back and forth while i get a better understanding of what you have done? instead of me asking hundreds of questions here in the comments? maybe i will be able to better explain what i want and then once i get it right i could update my question ?

Comment: is there a way for us to chat back and forth while i get a better understanding of what you have done? instead of me asking hundreds of questions here in the comments? maybe i will be able to better explain what i want and then once i get it right i could update my question ?

Comment: Well there is a way to go into a chatroom where you can talk more extensively, but I have never activated it actively. Usually it just comes up and "move comments to chat room?" and then it moves it over, but I have never actually created one...and the instructions on creating a chatroom are not very descriptive...

Comment: I see how to make a chatroom but it's not the same as moving the conversation into a chat-type area...those seem more of a permanent chat situation. Just ask here, it should eventually come up and ask to move the conversation over...plus I think if you have moderator tools you are able to force people into chat areas, a moderator did that to me once...but I don't have access to such tools at my current reputation.

Comment: What part are you having difficulties with specifically? How to actually submit it so the user doesn't have to put in their user/pass or how to check or which part?

Comment: okey so i have made a file called functions.php and included it the top of my products page with include_once. do i need to add c and b to a table inside my database? and how do i only show the specific content? as each description will have a different price to it.

Comment: my system (whole files and code) before i posted basically let any body go to products page and see product descriptions but if they wanted to see pricing they had to register and login with the registered account then if they go to the products page it showed the content ( i showed and hid the content using:

Comment: Well, you have to have a way to determine what kind of content can be viewed by what user type, you don't have to put a table inside you database. Right now, do you have database content stored that is either/or?

Comment: <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ?>
<p>Pricing below:</p>
<p><a class="link" href="logout.php" style="text-decoration:none">Logout</a></p>
<?php }else{ ?>
  <a class="link" href="login_page.php" style="text-decoration:none">login</a> or <a class="link" href="registration_page.php" style="text-decoration:none">Register</a>
<?php } ?> and it worked but now i want to add another statement that sort of says if you logged in with b or c show content for b or c. and that is why i have those 2 radio buttons on the login page.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I have in my function example, the first `if` checks logged in, the second is a *ternary* operator (basically a `true`/`false` comparison) to indicate if user is a `b` or `c` type (but in human-readable function names)

Comment: I will take your example from the comment and format it with my code snippets.

Comment: Ok updated, you just do `if/else` but you have to have already set the session view type at some point, either at login or what-have-you.

Comment: no the only content stored in database is username, password, email, and date. the content i want to show comes from if logged in show this content otherwise show login / register link nothing is stored in the database. and the show this content is basically text made into a table with duration and price. but i want a if logged in with b radio button show x content  but if logged in with c radio button show y content but i do not want user to have to register 2 accounts. sorry i think im just stupid.

Comment: Yeah, then what I am showing you is how you display different content based on how they checked the view button. If you want to permanently store the their type, you need to then store that in the database. If you want it to be only checked at login (so they could switch back and forth) keep it as you have. So, store in db permanently if you want it to be a setting created at the time of sign up, then you retrieve that setting when the user logs in

Comment: So, if I wanted to have a user type in my system, I would have the radio buttons on my sign up page. They would check off the type of user they were going to be, then that would store their username, password hash, and type. Then I would assign the type to session whenever they logged in. If you wanted them to just choose a type at login, so they could float back and forth, then you keep your radio buttons in your login form and don't store the user type in your database.

Comment: XD okey it works to the point of if not logged in it shows login or register link (in product page) and if i log in with check box c it displays content of $50 (which is for b) and if i use check box b it still only shows content for b $50. ?

Comment: Do `print_r($_SESSION);` to see what the view is set in the session.

Comment: it gives Array ( [username] => test [view_type] => b ) if i check c or b

Comment: Well, you set it at `b` so it would be correct if it says $50 because that view is a `b`. `isCorporate()` should be `false` and `isBirthday()` should be `true` if `view_type` equals `b`

Comment: If not logged in `isCorporate()` and `isBirthday()` both would be `false`. `!isLoggedIn()` would equal `true`.

Comment: yes it does that but if i set it at c which is corporate price then i should show $100 but it does not it still shows $50. and if it is not logged in and i go to that page then it shows correctly (it shows to log in or register to view pricing)

Comment: That would take some debugging, you need to see if it consistently is setting `b` at login. If so, you have to debug your login script or your form. When you log in, do `die(print_r($_POST,1));` See what is in the post.

Comment: would it make a difference if i change <input type="radio" name="radio" value="birthday" checked> Birthday Prices<br> to <input type="radio" name="radio" value="birthday" > Birthday Prices<br> is the checked maybe forcing it to be checked?

Comment: okey when i do die(print_r($_POSR,1)); it gives me Array ( [radio] => corporate [username] => test [password] => test [submit] => Login ) when i check c and Array ( [radio] => birthday [username] => test [password] => test [submit] => Login ) when i check b so that seems to be firing correctly

Comment: Oh the name is `radio`, then check `$_SESSION['view_type'] = (!empty($_POST['radio']) && $_POST['radio'] == 'corporate' )? 'c' : 'b';`